# What does the term "boresight", and what do the phrases "boresight adjustment" or "boresight calibration", mean in the context of laser scanning?

Tags: laser, optics, photonics, uav, scanning

I have been studying the laser scanning literature. In doing so, I often come across the term "boresight", and the phrases "boresight adjustment" or "boresight calibration". For example, see [this paper](http://www.riegl.com/uploads/tx_pxpriegldownloads/Boresight_Calibration_of_Mobile_Mapping_Systems.pdf). However, I have not seen any explanation of what these actually mean. What does the term "boresight", and what do the phrases "boresight adjustment" or "boresight calibration", mean in the context of laser scanning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In telecommunications and radar engineering, antenna boresight is the axis of maximum gain (maximum radiated power) of a directional antenna.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_boresight

In other words, it is the direction your radar or lidar beam is pointing. Calibration would be the process of figuring out how that axis is aligned with the rest of your system (car, plane, table, etc).  This is important because you often want to overlay data over the real world (e.g. for guidance or navigation).

Comment: But this is for antennas, so is it the same in the context of laser scanning?

Comment: Yes, the same word is used for both RADAR and LIDAR.

Answer (score 1):

" boresight  angles (are)  between  IMU  and  laser  scanner  of  a  MLS  system"

So the view of each system is a moving "boresight" and alignment is to minimize the error of the common views.

Comment: This really doesn't explain what they mean.

Comment: The paper describes how adjustments and calibration is done. I thought you want clarification as to the reference to bore and sighting with a laser scanner. Rifles use laser bore scanners, but the emitter is located in the bullet position and the viewer matches the target at minimum range. then offsets vertical for long range trajectory.  Here there are parallax and beam  corrections.

Comment: Here there are parallax and beam  corrections.https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&output=search&tbm=isch&q=What+is+boresight+angle?&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=wzddE7lh4H7GOM%252CSnWiGLMXgZjb4M%252C_